# Can I Start an On-Demand Scheduled Query with Multiple Eventarc Pub/Sub Triggers?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, event-arc

We have two different survey tools (Alice and Bob). Each tool is integrated as a data source with BigQuery and the data syncs into their own tables (`surveys_by_alice` and `surveys_by_bob`).

We want to update our current thinking in a special table based on the latest survey results (`current_thinking`).

What I have built so far:

1. an on-demand scheduled query that reads from `surveys_by_alice` and `surveys_by_bob` and updates `current_thinking`
2. a service account for this task with `BigQuery Admin` and `Cloud Run Invoker` permissions
3. I went to Cloud Logging and created a sink based on when data gets inserted into the first survey table (called `sink.surveys_by_alice`) and a Pub/Sub topic (called `topic.surveys_by_alice`)
4. I created a new cloud function with an Eventarc trigger based on the `topic.surveys_by_alice` Pub/Sub topic
5. I deployed the code and it successfully triggers the on-demand scheduled query whenever the `surveys_by_alice` table is updated

Now, I also want the same cloud function to launch the same scheduled query whenever `surveys_by_bob` gets updated.

I am not sure what to do because I started by creating a second sink (`sink.surveys_by_bob`) and Pub/Sub topic (`topic.surveys_by_bob`), but I realize that there does not appear to be a way to edit my existing cloud function to also be triggered by `topic.surveys_by_bob`).

[image: Cloud Functions settings with single Eventarc trigger]

Am I missing something?

One solution is to simply have any updates to `surveys_by_alice` and `surveys_by_bob` point to the same Pub/Sub topic `topic.surveys`, but that seems like a problem if I want to differentiate the two for other downstream events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, one solution is to point both logging sinks to one single pub/sub topic which will trigger your cloud funtion.

---

If you want to keep the logging sinks and pub/sub topics separate but only one cloud funtion, you can:

1. Change the the cloud function to be triggered by http request.
2. Create the 2 pub/sub topics
3. For each topic you create a push subscription pointing to the same url of the cloud function.
   [image: Pub/sub Subscription]

---

Last but not least, you can copy the cloud funtion and trigger the copy by the second topic (`topic.surveys_by_bob`). In this case you have 2 logging sinks, 2 pub/sub topics and 2 cloud functions